# Css Animation Iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am making a javascript slot machine for a jr. dev interview test. I have five "reels" which are columns with images arranged on top of each other vertically. The idea is to get the column to scroll down, reach the end, and return to the top smoothly so it looks like on fluid animation. I know there are JQuery libraries that do the heavy lifting, but I want to write my code from scratch. My current thought is to use CSS animation and keyframes to scroll to the bottom of the column in a fluid motion and start the animation with JQuery. Is there a way to make the animation jump back to the top of the column smoothly to create the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a keyframe to return to its previous state without jumping (in this case) from the bottom of the image back to the top. take advantage of the % values inside the keyframes.
`@keyframes Animation{
    0% {postion: 0;}
    25% {postion: 20;}
    50% {postion: 40;}
    75% {postion: 20;}
    100% {postion: 0;}
}`
 had to improvise the css since i dont know hop your actually moving the img.

this way the entire animation resets itself at the end  allowing for further  iterations with no visual jumping.